# Django with HAML, SASS, CoffeeScript and related compressors

Tags: python, django, haml, sass, coffeescript

I would like to use HAML-like templates together with SASS and CoffeeScript in a Django site. Currently I am looking into [DMSL](https://github.com/dasacc22/dmsl) for HAML templates, and recompiling SASS (Compass) and CoffeeScript files to CSS and JS (and compressing) every time I change them. For inline code, I could add some DMSL filters, however, this might be a slow approach.

One can also use [django_compressor](https://github.com/jezdez/django_compressor) to enable SASS, LESS and CoffeeScript in standard Django templates.

Can you recommend a better way to use HAML, SASS, and CoffeeScript in Django sites?

Comment: You might want to try http://elsdoerfer.name/files/docs/webassets/

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I recommend django_compressor for sass and coffeescript (I actually contributed to part of it supporting the precompilers :)

For HAML I was using HamlPy + Djaml which provides a generic usable template loader

Comment: No. What for? Djaml is completely transparent - you add 1 line to template loaders, and you're done.

Comment: Note that Djaml has now been integrated into the HamlPy codebase, so there is no need to use Djaml any more